# map an array of struct

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I have an array of struct containing several fields. I want to map the array to create another one of struct containing a subset of fields

```
struct History: {
   let field1: String
   let field2: String
   let field3: String
   let field4: String
}

struct SubHistory: {
   let field1: String
   let field2: String
}
```

I could use the for in loop. But It may be possible to use a map, no ?

Comment: can you add an example of the array you trying to map with an expected result ?

Comment: `let subHistoryArray = historyArray.map{SubHistory(field1: $0.field1, field2: $0.field2)}`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use `map` in the following way:

```
let histories: [History] // array of History structs
let subHistories = histories.map { SubHistory(field1: $0.field1, field2: $0.field2) }
```

Answer (score 5):

As a slight variation of [kiwisip's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802281/1187415): I would suggest to put the logic of “creating a SubHistory from a History” into a custom initializer:

```
extension SubHistory {
    init(history: History) {
        self.init(field1: history.field1, field2: history.field2)
    }
}
```

Then the mapping can be simply done as

```
let histories: [History] = ...
let subHistories = histories.map(SubHistory.init)
```

Putting the initializer into an extension has the advantage that the default memberwise initializer is still synthesized – attribution for this observation goes to @kiwisip!

Comment: And if you create the `init(history: History)` in an extension to `SubHistory`, you don't have to implement the default initializer as Swift will generate it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, whenever you have an `Array` , or any type implementing the [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection) protocol, where [`map` is defined](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2908394-map), you can use `map` to transform `[A]` into `[B]`.

[kiwisip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802281/809944) already gave a good answer, and [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802634/809944) suggested a nice variation.

Here's another one.

```
extension History {

  var subHistory: SubHistory { 
    return SubHistory(field1: field1, field2: field2)
  }
}

// use it like
let histories: [History] = [...]
let subHistories = histories.map { $0.subHistory }
```